# Low voltage switch (12v)

Tags: voltage, 12v, charging, controller

I am looking to build a circuit that will control a 120v battery charger through a relay, the circuit should turn the relay on when the battery goes below 11 volts and turn off the relay when it gos above 12 volts.

I also need to be able to adjust the "trigger" voltage. maybe 10 volts through 11 volts.. incremented by a tenth of a volt..

what this does is charge a 12v battery when the voltage goes below 11volts.

Currently I am doing it with two ebay purchased circuits and some fancy relay wiring.

circuit one trips a relay that is normally open to normally closed when voltage goes below 11 volts.. circuit board two when "triggered" by circuit board one closes it's relay for 60 minutes.

That relay (circuit bard 2) runs a 120v 30 amp relay that turns on a 100amp 12 volt power supply which charges 8 100ah deep cycle batteries.

I have the delay circuit boards (board 2). I can not find board 1. So I thought I'd reboot my teenage circuit making skills, but I can not seem to find a diagram to accomplish this..

Comment: This would be an ideal application for [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not a fan of the doctrine. Batteries should be kept as topped up as they can be.  Dipping a lead-acid battery to a high state of discharge will quickly age it and rob it of capacity.

Comment: Anything that touches mains power should be in a mains-rated enclosure (from the electrician's parts bin not the electronics parts bin) and should be UL listed not RU. Air conditioning contactors are a good source for 24V-coil mains relays. See also RiB, Aube, and transformer relays that sit on a 4x4 junction box lid. *So easy to do it right/safe*.

Answer (score 1):

To charge lead-acid batteries, you need a proper regulated or "smart" battery charger designed for that application.

A "smart" charger will have three charging states - bulk charge (full current until 14.4 Volts), acceptance (hold 14.4 Volts til current drops to an Amp or so), (I've forgotten the other term...)

12 Volts is not sufficient to charge a "12 Volt" lead-acid battery.  A fully-charged battery will be over 13 Volts.

If you have invested in 800 Ah of batteries, surely you can afford a proper charger to maintain them.